# WPF Ribbon Navigation Buttons - How to use

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, ribbon

If you create an empty WPF app, and replace the MainWindow.xaml with the following:

```
<ribbon:Ribbon xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary" />
```

(Note the use of the Ribbon class, not RibbonWindow as is used in most tutorials on the subject.)

Then delete MainWindow.cs and run the app.

It will give you a nice looking window with IE like navigation buttons and under that, the actual ribbon bar.

[image: Ribbon with Navigation]

How do I use those navigation buttons?  I have found lots of info on the rest of the Ribbon Bar, but not the navigation buttons.

I have an app with has a navigation stack and I just need to be able to fire an event when the user clicks forward/backward so I can have the app navigate.  And of course, I need to be able to enable or disable them depending on the navigation stack.

I have looked, but I don't see any property of the RibbonClass that exposes the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigation buttons are part of the navigation mechanics built into WPF since its Avalon times. They have nothing in common with Ribbon.

See details here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/navigation-overview

Answer (score 0):

Well, after no responses here, and no luck Googling, I have come to the conclusion that the navigation buttons are not officially supported, and there are no properties exposing them.  I went as far as searching through the source code which is available as part of the [WPF Ribbon Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11877) but I found nothing.

So am going to mark this as answered for now.